# Akka actor initializing a variable multiple times causing multiple rows

Tags: database, hibernate, concurrency, akka, one-to-many

I have an actor that initializes an object and then saves it to database

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setProp(prop);
dao.save(myObject);
```

In the database I see

```
MyObject table
id prop 
1  prop
2  prop
3  prop
4  prop
```

I am trying to resolve why this is, nowhere else have I initialized this object out side this actor. Given the ids in the database column are differnt, the object does seem like initialized 4 times. Is this because the actor is initializing this 4 times? How should I manage this actor?>

I create the actor in the following way

```
    Props MyActorProps = Props.create(MyActor.class);
    getContext().actorOf(MyActorProps).tell(...mymessage);
```

Doesn't actorOf() ensure that there is just one instance of the actor?

Comment: after `getContext().actorOf(MyActorProps).tell(...mymessage);` add `println("actor told");` to make sure actor is triggered once.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing quite a bit of relevant bits of the code (you are using context in the creation, which means you are in an actor, but don't tell us if there is only one of those or how the parents are created, etc...), but:

Wheny you do `.actorOf()` at the context or system level, you create a new instance of the actor whose `actorRef` you are returned.

You can ensure there is only one by creating actors with names! From [the doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#creating-actors):

*The name parameter is optional, but you should preferably name your actors, since that is used in log messages and for identifying actors. The name must not be empty or start with $, but it may contain URL encoded characters (eg. %20 for a blank space). If the given name is already in use by another child to the same parent an InvalidActorNameException is thrown.*

This is how you create an actor with name:

`getContext().actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class), "myChild");`

There are things like ClusterSingletons that help you ensure only one instance exist, but they are beyond the scope of vanilla akka-core.